# Python Selenium use dictionary for one general xpath for locator class?

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, xpath

is it possible to get one 'general xpath' for several xpaths by using a python dictionary?
In a locators class I want to locate all the elements in a formula to automatically type in data (for automation testing).
And in the XPATH, all that changes per field is just input'number+1' each time.
So I created this dictionary in python:

```
class CreateLabLocators(object):
formulaDictionary = {"labname":12,
                     "city":13,
                     "state":14,
                     "zipcode":15,
                     "street":16,
                     "number":17,
                     "country":18,
                     "website":19,
                     "phone":20,
                     "fax":21,
                     }
```

Is it possible to use the key and the value of the dictionary to have a locator for each field?
So instead of this:

```
labname = (By.XPATH, "//input[@id='__input12-inner']")
city = (By.XPATH, "//input[@id='__input13-inner']")
state = (By.XPATH, "//input[@id='__input14-inner']")
zipcode = (By.XPATH, "//input[@id='__input15-inner']")
street = (By.XPATH, "//input[@id='__input16-inner']")
number = (By.XPATH, "//input[@id='__input17-inner']") (etc...)
```

Have something more general. How would I implement this?
So that if I want to call the locator outside the class, I should be able to do it in a way like...

```
find_element(*CreateLabLocators.city).send_keys("abc")
find_element(*CreateLabLocators.zipcode).send_keys("123")
```

and so on.
On a side note, I am using Python 2.7.

Comment: Can you clarify why do you need to define dict inside class? Or why do you need that class at all?

Comment: Please don't do this. I understand you feel like it would be more efficient, etc. but sometimes the straightforward way is the easiest and best way. If an element changes with your dictionary system, you will have to look a few different places to find where the change needs to go. With a simple locator list, you will go to that specific locator and fix it.

Answer (score 1):

In your exact case you can simply do following:

```
for index in range(12, 22):
    locator = (By.XPATH, "//input[@id='__input%s-inner']" % index)
    #  do something with locator
```

Or if you want to use values from dictionary:

```
for item in formulaDictionary:
    locator = (By.XPATH, "//input[@id='__input%s-inner']" % formulaDictionary[item])
    #  do something with locator
```

Answer (score 1):

You could you do something like this -

```
def xpath_builder(which_one):
     first_half = r"//input[@id='__input"
     second_half = r"-inner']"
     return (first_half + formulaDictionary[which_one] + second_half)

your_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_builder(city))
```